# Application is stop in between and can't response

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to insert data in coredata and redirect to the tableView Controller. But in between application is stop and can't response it and not crash. stop point is define in between code.

```
- (IBAction)submitData:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newContact;
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *number;
    number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [number setValue:_numberText.text forKey:@"number"];
    [newContact setValue:_nameText.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:_addressText.text forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:_emailText.text forKey:@"email"];
    [newContact setValue:_othernoText.text forKey:@"otheNo"];
    [newContact setValue:_hobbyText.text forKey:@"hobby"];
    [newContact setValue:_contactText.text forKey:@"contact"];
    NSError *error; // here application is stop can't response it.
    [context save:&error];

    _nameText.text = @"";
    _addressText.text = @"";
    _emailText.text = @"";
    _othernoText.text = @"";
    _hobbyText.text = @"";
    _contactText.text = @"";

    TableViewController *table = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How is NSManagedObjectContext instantiated?

Comment: Is it due to a breakpoint?

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext is from AppDelgate. and it's work properly but i don't know why stop working.

Comment: No breakpoints.